# Check if object exist in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am trying to return a boolean.
I have this firebase list array

```
{
  "users" : {
    "AsvLATYdwhg6BB8rgMKn2n" : {
      "avatar" : "httDJid_DnWXwo/photo.jpg",
      "bio" : "say something about you!"
    },
    "SFmtrI0ta5PsqYkgqZuJ" : {
      "avatar" : "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/103_n.jpg?o",
      "bio" : "say something about you!",
    }
  }
```

I want to check if one of the keys exist in the array.

```
 _isInArray(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }

      return false;
  }
```

Then I run it:

```
 if(_isInArray(SFmtrI0ta5PsqYkgqZuJo2EG, array) {
      console.log("Is in array");
    }else {
       console.log('not in array');
     }
```

But it seems I am missing something. It keeps just saying (not in array).

**BTW:** I am using angular2. Is there is a better way of doing this in typescript , if not vanilla JavaScript is just okay.

Comment: Just use plain TypeScript or JavaScript. There is nothing special to Angular2

Comment: I did the JavaScript. But I still don't get the desired result.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: check lodash a helper library to reconstruct the data's